# Count values in groups

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with student IDs separated in groups. I need a handy way to count the total number of students in each group and populate it after the last row of each group (marked with `??`)

[image]

Currently I just enter `=COUNT()` and then manually figure out the top and bottom borders of the range for each group. Not convenient at all.

I was thinking that a possible solution could be one of the following:

1. A some kind of **pivot table** permutation. I failed on this one.
2. Excel **Data->Outline->Subtotals** functions. Again, fail. It keeps creating new rows in my table.
3. A universal **formula** that can be pasted into each `??` cell. Not the most graceful solution, but still would do.
4. A **macro**. As a last remedy if nothing else works.

Comment: If you rearrange your data so that Group Name and Student ID are filled in for each row, with no white space (and no Total rows of course) it will be easy to pivot. If at all possible, that's what you should do. In the long run poorly arranged source data, such as this, will waste many hours of your life.

Comment: True, I was thinking about it. Unfortunately, no way for me to access the generating script. And copy/pasting the group name for each student record (100s of students per group in dozens of groups) doesn't seem to be too handy either. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: I was afraid it was out of your control. You actually shouldn't have to do individual copy/pastes though. Take a look at this post:http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/enter-data-into-many-cells-at-once/. Scroll down to the formula part. Once you've done that you can easily Sort or Filter away the blank headers. Then pivot!

Comment: +1 to Doug.  If you _really_ can't change the source data, then add a helper column adjacent to your table containing a formula that yields the group name on each row, and pivot on that

Comment: @chris, I *can* change the sheet once I am working on it, but I *cannot* change the generating it script.

@Doug, okay the Select Blanks, Ctrl+Enter does the trick pretty well to the point where I can pivot and get the numbers. Now my ultimate goal was to fill in the yellow `??` fields though. So I guess I'd have to copy/paste back from the pivot sheet..

Comment: Just to be clear, you cant use the pivot table with grouped totals as your final product? From your original question, I thought that was an option. I've been focused on your current sheet as a data source, with the pivot table as the report.

Comment: Actually, on the second thought I think I could give it a try. The fact is that there are other fields that I have to subtotal the same way at the same time, but what the heck I'll just try adding them into the pivot too.

Comment: I'd say that's your best bet. There's a bit of a learning curve to pivot tables, so it's good to step back a bit and do a bit of reading on them. The flip side is that they are a very powerful tool that's much less amorphous than Excel in general, and once you've got the hang of them you can create complex reports fast. Multiple fields are easily do-able.

Comment: I was trying to move this comment thread to chat, but can't see how to. Clicking on the chat link on the top throws me to meta.stack which I don't have enough reputation points to start a chat :-/ Anyways, the next question I have is automation. Once I figured out all the steps needed to create that pivot (fill up the blanks, stack up needed fields, apply filters) how do I make it over and over again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following steps will calculate the subtotals while preserving the structuring and formatting of your worksheet.

1. Put this formula in cell C1 and copy the formula down the column:

   ```
   =IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Total",A1))),COUNTA(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-7),A:A,0)+1&".B"&(MATCH(A1,A:A,0)+1))),IF(B1="","",B1))
   ```
2. Apply a conditional format to cell C1 with the formula rule =(MOD(ROW(C1),2)=0) and blue fill to match the shading on the other rows. Copy the format down the column using Paste Special Format.
3. Either hide column B, or copy the values in column C to column B using Paste Special Values and hide Column C. If you decide to copy the values to column B, you won't need to set the conditional formats.

Here is what the formula does:

- First, check whether the formula's row is a Total row, by searching the cell in column A of the row for the word "Total," using the SEARCH function.

  **If the word "Total" is found:**

  Determine the range in the worksheet of the student IDs for the group for that total row:

  *a) Identify the rows in which the words "GroupX" and "GroupX Total" are found by using the MATCH function. With that, you know that the IDs for the group are in a range that starts at, say, row x and ends at row y.*

  *b) With the starting and ending row numbers, construct the address range in which the IDs lie, which has to be the string "B" + (row x) + "." + "B" + (row y).*

  *c) Turn the string into a range reference that can actually used in a formula using the INDIRECT function.*

  Count the number of students in the group using the COUNTA function and the range, and show that as the formula's result.

  **If the word "Total" is not found**

  Check whether the cell in column B is empty

  *a) If it is empty, show a blank as the formula's result*

  *b) if it is not empty, it must be a student ID, so show the ID as the formula's result.*

Answer (score 2):

Add a column (I usually add it to the LEFT of the existing matrix) where you enter a formula from row 2 onwards that fills the blanks in the old column A. Then the old matrix including your new column can be used in a pivot.

1. So Insert a column left of your matrix, this is column A now. Put a header in Cell A1, for example "Group Name1"
2. Enter the following formula in cell B2 and extend it to the end:
   `=IF(B2="",A1,B2)` This way your blanks will be filled.
3. Now apply a pivot on this matrix and there you are.

Maybe not the nicest looking solution, but its quick and works well.

Answer (score 0):

If u have table like this

Students id      Name of students  group   ........

then u can use countif/countifs formula